# OnClick Error android

Tags: android, onclick

Class ActivityAdd created, onClick  defined. Any buttons and classes on this layout are working. Please tell what's wrong here?

My error log :

```
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4206)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3596)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    ... 11 more
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mk.run4rebate.ActivityAdd
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at mk.run4rebate.ActivityAddSearch.startAddActivity(ActivityAddSearch.java:144)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at mk.run4rebate.ActivityAddSearch.activities(ActivityAddSearch.java:115)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    at mk.run4rebate.ActivityAddSearch.AddOnClick(ActivityAddSearch.java:72)
12-20 10:48:47.780: E/AndroidRuntime(21934):    ... 14 more
```

AddOnClick method:

```
public void AddOnClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, ActivityAdd.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

layout Button:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageBig"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageBig"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_button_add_top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_button_add_left"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="AddOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/main_button_add" />
```

Corrected to full Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="mk.run4rebate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto" >
    <permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityStart"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityRegistration"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />
          <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityAccount"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />

           <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityAddSearch"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />  

            <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityAdd"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />  

            <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityCategoryList"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />  

            <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivitySearch"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />  
        <activity android:name="mk.run4rebate.ActivityOption"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
        />  
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party jar file?

Comment: check whether your manifest have declaration for `ActivityAdd` activity

Comment: where is your `onClick()` code?

Comment: how you are calling AddOnClick  ? show me structure

Comment: Please add full AndroidManifest to your question. Also, what's the package name where ActivityAdd is?

Answer (score 0):

If you using external jar be sure that you export it to your apk.
You can do this by
`Go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export"`
and check all exported libraries